# c# How to get from a Json string to class instance then calling method

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json-deserialization

I have a (sql) table with these entries:

Table:

```
Type (varchar)     Json (varchar)
MyClassA           { "Id": 1, "Name": "OneName" }   
MyClassB           { "Id": 2, "Name": "TwoName" }
```

I need to call a method in ClassA and/or ClassB to change the Name property.

Something like the next code:

```cs
public void Test(string type, string json)
{
   Type type = Type.GetType($"MyNamespace.a.b.{type}, MyDll");

   // Some code here....
   // - Casting to IData    ??
   // - var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);       ??
   // - var obj = JsonConectt.DeserializeObject<type>(json)  ??
   // - var x = Convert.Change(...) ??


   instance.DoSomething("bazinga");

}


public interface IData 
{
   void DoSomething();
}

public class MyClassA : IData
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public void DoSomething(string newName)
   {
       Name = newName;
   }
}

public class MyClassB : IData
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public void DoSomething(string newName)
   {
       name = $"{Id}, {newName}";
   }
}
```

Attempt A:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var ins = obj as IData;
// ins = null
```

Attempt B:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
// failed
```

Attempt C:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeseriallizeObject<type>(json);
// Not allowed to use 'type' in this way.
```

Comment: `var obj = JsonConvert.DeseriallizeObject<IData>(json)` maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type) as IData;
```

See [HERE](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) for the official documentation. The second parameter will define the type to be deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you have to create a specialized type for each generic call which normally is done at runtime. Wha you need to do to create that type by yourself is to use some reflection:

```
public void Test(string type, string json)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType($"MyNamespace.a.b.{type}, MyDll");
    // from all method named "DeserializeObject"
    // find the one that is generic method
    MethodInfo deserializeObjectMethodInfo = typeof(JsonConvert)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name == "DeserializeObject");
    // create a specialized method for the requested type
    // same as you would call DeserializeObject<type>
    MethodInfo specializedDeserializeObject = deserializeObjectMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    // invoke that method with json as parameter
    // and cast it to IData
    IData data = (IData)specializedDeserializeObject.Invoke(null, json);
    // do whatever you want with the deserialized object
    data.DoSomething("bazinga");
}
```